# the media condition repeat in each column

Tags: css, sass

hi I"m working in one project, and i have create media condition for my column in Sass.

this the code

```
// for Mobile media - 320px width
@mixin mobile{
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    width: 300px;
}
}
```

and this my loop for my column

```
@for $col from 1 through $grid-cols{
.col-#{$col}{
    @include mobile;
}
}
```

and my $grid-cols = 12

so this my css output

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .col-1 {
  width: 300px; } }

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .col-2 {
  width: 300px; } }
```

etc... till .co-12

i need my output like this

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
   .col-1, .col-2 {width:300px;}
```

please, any hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to use a [SASS placeholder](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#placeholder_selectors_) in order to achieve that output. Replace your mixin:

```
@mixin mobile{
  @media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

with a placeholder:

```
%mobile {
  @media only screen and (max-width:767px){
    width: 300px;
  }
}
```

and call it with the `@extend %mobile;` instead of `@include mobile;` in your loop.

See [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/sass-mixin-placeholder/) for a very nice explanation on differences between mixins and placeholders.